# Accessing outlook Contacts folder through javascript Cross browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, outlook

I have a website that has a functionality to Add and sync a Distribution list to Client's Contacts folder in outlook or selected sub folder under Contacts.

This website was running previously in IE 7. Now to be upgraded to IE 11, Firefox and Chrome.

I read the old code and found that they had made a dll and called that through javascript in a way I didn't understand and works only in IE 7. Code is as follows.

They made a constant for the dll:

```
Public Shared OutlookUtility As String =
  "OutlookClientV6.dll#OutlookClientV6.OutlookUtility"
```

and then made a javascript object at runtime and set its class to this constant

```
div_OutlookClient.InnerHtml = String.Format("<object
id='OutlookUtility' name='OutlookUtility' classid='{0}'></object>' >",
Common.OutlookUtility)
```

then called this dll's methods as

```
var data = document.getElementById('SyncToOutlook_OutlookUtility').GetAllContactFolder();
```

This code works properly in IE 7 but not in other browsers.

Also, the other issue is this dll uses ActiveX which works only in IE.

As the Outlook on client side is being accessed it make sense to use javascript for the entire operation and not make a server side call.

How can I get this concept working, cross-browser?

Comment: Updated code view, and added a question

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use Exchange I'd recommend using EWS instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.